# How to generate SSTable files with Hadoop map-reduce in Cassandra?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, mapreduce, bulk-load

I have 500GB data on HDFS to transfer to Cassandra cluster.  I think  the fastest way is to use Cassandra `sstableloader` to bulk load `sstable` files into Cassandra.

Cassandra 3.x has provided Client API `CQLSSTableWriter` to generate `sstable` files, which seems suitable for a single machine, but it is slow; how can I generate `sstables` by using map-reduce？

Hbase has provided tools to generate Hbase table formatted files by map-reduce from  hdfs data, before bulkloaded to hbase. Does Cassandra have a similar method?

************ added on 2017/02/21 after tried a lot ********
With some hints from answers, I search with some keywords and combine some  materials together to form a test program below, but seems missing some configuration or logics （
Error: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]） when starting reduce period. I think even if I solve this problem, new problems are in front. So If some one can provide me a complete sample of CqlBulkOutpuFormat in hadoop MR, because I was guessing something before.

I think generating sstable files in HDFS by hadoop mr doesn't need the information of a certaion Cassandra cluster, just shema and insert format is ok. What's more, reading hdfs files and generating SSTABLE files doesn't seem to need both map and reduce methods. This is what I doubt on some information on Internet.

here is my codes, maybe many mistakes in your eyes, just show I have tried.

```
package hadooptest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper;
import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlBulkOutputFormat;
import org.apache.directory.api.util.ByteBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;




public class CassandraBulkImporter extends Configured implements Tool{

private static final String CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE_NAME = "yanbo";
private static final  String CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME = "test";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new
                  CassandraBulkImporter(), args);
            System.exit(exitCode);
}


 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //配置信息
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

         Job job =   Job.getInstance(conf, "CassandraBulkImporter");
         job.setJobName(CassandraBulkImporter.class.getName());
         job.setJarByClass(CassandraBulkImporter.class);
         job.setOutputFormatClass(CqlBulkOutputFormat.class);
                // 1.2对输入数据进行格式化处理的类
         job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
         job.setMapperClass(HdfsMapper.class);
         job.setReducerClass(ReducerToCassandra.class);

          job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
          job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

          FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
         ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(),"10.149.11.15");

         ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(),"Murmur3Partitioner");

         ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");

         ConfigHelper.setOutputKeyspace(job.getConfiguration(),CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE_NAME);
         ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(
                     job.getConfiguration(),
                    CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE_NAME,
                    CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME
           );
        //Set the properties for CqlBulkOutputFormat

        String KEYSPACE = "quote";
        String TABLE = "user_audience";
        String SCHEMA = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s.%s (" +
                                                              "id ascii, " +
                                                              "audience_ids ascii, " +
                                                              "PRIMARY KEY (id) " +
                                                          ")", KEYSPACE, TABLE);
        String INSERT_STMT = String.format("INSERT INTO %s.%s (" +
                "id, audience_ids" +
            ") VALUES (" +
                "?, ?" +
            ")", KEYSPACE, TABLE);

        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job,
                CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME, 
                CqlBulkOutputFormat.class, Object.class, List.class);

        CqlBulkOutputFormat.setTableSchema(
         job.getConfiguration(), CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME, 
                SCHEMA);

        CqlBulkOutputFormat.setTableInsertStatement(
                 job.getConfiguration(),
                CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME, INSERT_STMT);


        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

 }

 static class HdfsMapper extends 
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>  {
    public HdfsMapper(){}
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String s = value.toString();
        context.write(key, value);
    }
}

 static class ReducerToCassandra extends 
      Reducer<LongWritable, Text, Object,  List<ByteBuffer>> {
    public ReducerToCassandra(){}
    private MultipleOutputs multipleOutputs;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      protected void setup(Context context) 
               throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(context);
     }

    @Override
     public void reduce(LongWritable id, 
     Iterable<Text> values,  Context context) 
     throws IOException,   InterruptedException {

         for(Text value : values )
         { 
             List<ByteBuffer> bVariables = 
                new ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ();
             for(String cell: value.toString().split("\001"))
             {                   
                 ByteBuffer buf  = new ByteBuffer();             
                 buf.append(cell.getBytes());
                 bVariables.add( buf);
             }
             multipleOutputs.write(CASSANDRA_TABLE_NAME,
       null,    bVariables);
          }           
     }
  }
}
```

17/02/20 21:14:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/02/20 21:14:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1487380305027_71639_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:/// for local files or file:/// for remote files. Aborting. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlBulkRecordWriter.(CqlBulkRecordWriter.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlBulkRecordWriter.(CqlBulkRecordWriter.java:94)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlBulkOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlBulkOutputFormat.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlBulkOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlBulkOutputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.(ReduceTask.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Comment: You do not have to apply to join the mailing list, just send an email. See http://cassandra.apache.org/community/ (click subscribe). You can just send an email with questions

Comment: Have you looked at CqlBulkOutputFormat ?

Comment: @Chris Lohfink  that seems right way, but I can't work out successful codes, Do you have some sample codes?

Comment: Does Cassandra provide official sample of  key functiosn like CqlBulkOutputFormat? I can't find in official-site or document. But I think there must be some samples, otherwise the  users read source codes of the API or guess when they first get face the problem?

Comment: @Yanbo Did you ever find a solution to this? This would be really good to have a way to do that... Yes SSTABLES are slow to generate on a single machine specially when you are dealing with 500GB.